# Is better to have multiple collections with thousands of documents or one collection with 100 million documents?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm migrating a MySql table which has 100 million rows to a MongoDB database, this table stores companys documents and what difference them are the column company_id. I was wondering if have multiple collections on mongodb would be faster than just one collection, for example, each company would have it own collection (collections: company_1, company_2, company_3...) and store only documents from that company, so I will not need to filter then as I would need to do if I just had 1 big collection and in every document there would be a column named company_id that would be used to filter documents.
Which method would perform best in this case?

EDIT:
Here's a JSON document example: https://pastebin.com/T5m2tbaY

```
{"_id":"5d8b8241ae0f000015006142","id_consulta":45254008,"company_id":7,"tipo_doc":"nfe","data_requisicao":"2019-09-25T15:05:35.155Z","xml":Object...
```

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what data would be in a single document.

Comment: Put them in the same collection and index field `company_id`.

Comment: @barrypicker I'll have 1 date field, 1 int field, 1 field to identify what's the document type (nfe, nfce, cte, cteos, mdfe or cfe) and another field that will store a object which has dozens of nested objects (that's a XML file converted to object) and I'll need to make a lot of filters in the nested objects of this field

Comment: @barrypicker here's an example of a document: https://pastebin.com/T5m2tbaY

Comment: @Marcelo, thanks for providing example data.  I did not see the company_id in the example.  Is it under a different name?  (UPDATE - Nevermind - I see id_empresa)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to change it to english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have one collection and one document per company, with company specific details in the document, assuming the details do not exceed 16MB in size.  Place an index on company id for performance reasons.  If performance conditions are not meeting expectations scale vertically - i.e., add memory, CPU, disk IO, and network enhancements to increase performance.  If that does not suffice, consider sharding the collection across multiple hosts.

Comment: Is it still better even each document will store a large JSON Object? Please see my edit

Comment: Yes, this is the idea, to avoid lookups.  All relevant data is stored in a single document and fetched by indexed key.  But, you do have a 16MB limit on document size.  Document schema design matters.  Some structures perform better than others.  For example, an array of simple integers performs better during fetch that an array of sub documents.

Comment: By the way, your example document is almost 6k.  This is tiny, not large.  Assuming this example is actually representative of real data there is no concern on impact of performance based on the size of the documents.